# Alias database in oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

If I have an oracle 11g database set up so that I can access it with

```
sqlplus user/pass@localhost:1521/ora11
```

However, I was wondering whether it is possible to set an alias to access it via:

```
sqlplus user/pass@ora11
```

I can set the oracle SID and connect through

```
export ORACLE_SID=ora11
sqlplus user/pass
```

However, if I have more than one database, ie ORA10 -> oracle 10 and ORA11 -> oracle 11, then I'd prefer to connect as

```
sqlplus user/pass@ORA10
sqlplus user/pass@ORA11
```

rather than having to type out localhost or set ORACLE_SID each time.

It would also be useful to do this if I'm trying to access remote oracle databases and don't want to have to remember the IP/PORT/SID everytime I wish to connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an entry to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` for each database you want to connect to:

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA11)
 )
)
```

You can now connect to this database using `sqlplus user/pass@ORA11`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but on my ORACLE 11 server these TNS entries are created automatic, when I create the databases

Comment: Yes, the server generates them automatically (because it will need to act as a client if you create a database link) but you can add extra aliases if you need them, or maintain a separate per-user tnsnames.ora (`$HOME/.tnsnames.ora`, from memory).

Comment: [René Nyffenegger's page](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/network/connection.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

On Client side you can use TNSNANES.ORA to do this. But similar to ODBC settings this defines the names only for one client. Different Clients can use different names.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this entry instead

```
SERVICE11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SID = INSTANCE11)
 )
)
```

It's much better to name your instance and your service mimicking the concepts. Hence, the name SERVICE11 to represent the concept of service, and INSTANCE11 to represent the concept of instance. For service related to Oracle 10g, you can have:

```
SERVICE10 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1520))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SID = INSTANCE10)
 )
)
```

You must setup two listener, each listening to different port value. It seems to me you want to use several DBMSs. As you see, there is no database involved in the tnsnames.ora. Hence the phrase 'connect to database' is wrong.

After setting up the two listeners and the related listener-config file, put entry of both services in the tnsnames.ora in your client-host. You can then

sqlplus username/password@service10
sqlplus username/password@service11